# VS2005 Resource Editor Keeps Eating my #ifdef's

Tags: visual-studio-2005, mfc, rc

The resource editor keeps wiping out code of this form in my .rc:

```
#ifndef V2
IDB_SPLASHSCREEN        BITMAP                  "res\\xyz v1.bmp"
#else
IDB_SPLASHSCREEN        BITMAP                  "res\\xyz v2.bmp"
#endif
```

Anyone know of a workaround?  Better way to accomplish the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MFC projects in Visual Studio normally contain a .rc2 file, which is intended for user-defined resources. If you add your bitmap resources to this file, they won't be modified by the Visual Studio resource editor.

You can read more about this [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk.aspx), and there's some good information in the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/95361/visual-studio-2005-rc-file-includes) here on StackOverflow.