# How can I share same Product Version between two Visual C++ projects?

Tags: visual-studio

I have 2 Visual C++ projects which both have an RC file where the Field Product Version is defined. How can I make both projects to get this version from a global place? Global RC file or what solutions are there?

Comment: create a global `version.h` file and include it from both rc files

Comment: I think you can just  modify the version info manually only.

Comment: @aleguna could you give an example what needs to be in the version.h file ?

Comment: @donnib, open your rc file in any text editor (e.g.  notepad.exe) and cut-paste the version section into `version.h`. Then include `version.h` in rc file using this method http://stackoverflow.com/questions/95361/visual-studio-2005-rc-file-includes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What works well for me is adding two "Solution Items". One is a .h file that `#defines` some version strings, and another is the .rc file that has an include to the .h and `BLOCK "StringFileInfo"` that uses the defines.

Individual resource files for each project use a [`TEXTINCLUDE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t3612sk%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to bring in the contents of the solution's .rc.

That is a lot to take in. Let me show you what I mean...

**1)** The two solution items are added as so:

[image: Solution Items]

**2)** `version.h` has some #defines that will be used in VersionInfo.rc2

```
#define SOLUTIONFILEVERSION 1,00,0000,00000
#define SOLUTIONFILEVERSIONSTRING "1,00,0000,00000"
#define COPYRIGHT "Copyright 2012"
#define PRODUCTNAME "Your product name"
#define COMPANYNAME "Your company name"
```

**3)** VersionInfo.rc2 uses the defines

```
#include "version.h"
VS_VERSION_INFO VERSIONINFO
 FILEVERSION SOLUTIONFILEVERSION
 PRODUCTVERSION SOLUTIONFILEVERSION
 FILEFLAGSMASK 0x3fL
#ifdef _DEBUG
 FILEFLAGS 0x1L
#else
 FILEFLAGS 0x0L
#endif
 FILEOS 0x4L
 FILETYPE 0x2L
 FILESUBTYPE 0x0L
BEGIN
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        BLOCK "040904b0"
        BEGIN
            VALUE "CompanyName", COMPANYNAME
            VALUE "FileVersion", SOLUTIONFILEVERSIONSTRING
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", COPYRIGHT
            VALUE "ProductName", PRODUCTNAME
            VALUE "ProductVersion", SOLUTIONFILEVERSIONSTRING
        END
    END
    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    BEGIN
        VALUE "Translation", 0x409, 1200
    END
END
```

You will want a new line at the end of this file to make the resource compiler happy when it is included in the next step.

Another field you might like to set is "FileDescription" but that is typically on a per-project basis. Remember, this can contain anything you would like to be shared between your projects.

**4)** Include the VersionInfo.rc2 in each process. This is done by right clicking on the each project's .rc in the *Resource View* and selecting *Resource Includes*.

Add to the *Compile-time directives*: `#include "../VersionInfo.rc2"`

[image: Compile-time directives]

This could be done manually by adding the following to the project's .rc file but it is probably better to let Visual Studio manage everything it can for you.

```
3 TEXTINCLUDE 
BEGIN
    "#include ""../VersionInfo.rc2""\r\n"
    "\0"
END

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//
#include "../VersionInfo.rc2"
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Phew....that was a mouthful. But now you should be able to change your product versions from one spot.

Comment: thank you very much. I tried your suggestion but it doesn't work. I created the version.h file and made the defines then i created the VersionInfo.rc2 and included it in the main RC file of the project. I also added both the version.h and VersionInfo.rc2 in the project. One thing which you did not mention is to remove the Version stuff from the main RC file. I did that as well. When building the project i get on warnings/errors and the dll has empty all the fields so it seems like the version info does not get thru. I don't know exactly what i am doing wrong. My IDE is Visual Studio 2009

Comment: You mention setting FileDescription on a per project basis. Any suggestions for doing that? Can there be another `BLOCK "StringFileInfo"` in a project specific .rc file in addition to this shared one?

Comment: I went ahead and tried to add a second version info block and that generates an error as I suspected it would. Still looking for a way to include the project specific values.

Comment: Do you guys have an idea of how to add these rc files in msbuild to run on teamcity ?

Comment: @Ani I've never used Teamcity, but there shouldn't be any problem following the steps in this answer, then pointing msbuild at your `.sln`.

Answer (score 0):

Ok i have solve it.

I had to add following as well at the bottom of the project's recource file

```
/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Generated from the TEXTINCLUDE 3 resource.
//

#include "VersionInfo.rc2"

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

Now everything works great. Thanks

Comment: I'm glad you got it working. I've updated the last step in my answer to hopefully make it easier for anyone else following along in the future.