# How to get version info from resources?

Tags: winapi, visual-c++, resources

I have the Version Info in resources declared:

```
100 VERSIONINFO
FILEVERSION 1,0,0,2
PRODUCTVERSION 1,0,0,2
FILEOS VOS_NT
FILETYPE VFT_APP
{
    BLOCK "StringFileInfo"
    {
        BLOCK "000004b0"
        {
            VALUE "FileDescription", "My application"
            VALUE "FileVersion", "1.0.0.2"
            VALUE "InternalName", "app.exe"
            VALUE "LegalCopyright", "Copyright ©  2012 by David."
            VALUE "OriginalFilename", "app.exe"
            VALUE "ProductName", "app"
            VALUE "ProductVersion", "1.0.0.2"
            VALUE "Assembly Version", "1.0.0.2"
        }
    }

    BLOCK "VarFileInfo"
    {
        VALUE "Translation", 0x0000 0x04B0
    }
}
```

I am getting Version Info this way:

```
HRSRC hResInfo;
HGLOBAL hResData;
LPCVOID pRes;
UINT uLen;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *lpFfi;

hResInfo = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(100), RT_VERSION);
MessageBox(0, "FindResource", 0,0);

hResData = LoadResource(hInst, hResInfo);
MessageBox(0, "LoadResource", 0,0);

pRes = LockResource(hResData);
MessageBox(0, "LockResource", 0,0);

VerQueryValue(pRes, "\\" ,(LPVOID*)&lpFfi, &uLen);
MessageBox(0, "VerQueryValue", 0,0);

FreeResource(hResData);

DWORD dwFileVersionMS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionMS;
DWORD dwFileVersionLS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionLS;

DWORD dwLeftMost     = HIWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
DWORD dwSecondLeft   = LOWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
DWORD dwSecondRight  = HIWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
DWORD dwRightMost    = LOWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
```

In function VerQueryValue is an error, because program breaks (MessageBox with text "VerQueryValue" doesn't show) and Visual C++ shows me the following message:

> First-chance exception at 0x77bf15a5 in ProxyCU.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x00483192.

How to repair this code?

Regards, David

Comment: I usually factor out where the version information is defined, [as shown here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13607986/how-can-i-share-same-product-version-between-two-visual-c-projects/13608454#13608454), so when it comes time to use it in code, it is a compiler define rather than a call to `LoadResource()`. If you cannot get your code to work, you may consider it an option.

Comment: I suggest check error code after LoadResource() (@ERR watch in debugger, or GetLastError). Also, check that this address, 0x00483192, is inside memory pointed by pRes.

Comment: Completely unrelated to the question, but why is your version resource at id 100? As far as I can tell it is expected to be at id 1 which is VS_VERSION_INFO

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`VerQueryValue()` cannot access version info from the original resource directly.  You must make a copy of the resource in memory, then pass that memory to `VerQueryValue()` instead.  The reason is because `VerQueryValue()` is designed to work with `GetFileVersionInfo()`, which requires a user-allocated block of writable memory and performs certain fixups within that memory.  Accessing the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct does not require the fixups, but the memory block must still be writable.  You cannot pass the original resource directly to `VerQueryValue()` because it is read-only memory.

Try this instead:

```
HRSRC hResInfo;
DWORD dwSize;
HGLOBAL hResData;
LPVOID pRes, pResCopy;
UINT uLen;
VS_FIXEDFILEINFO *lpFfi;

hResInfo = FindResource(hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(100), RT_VERSION);
dwSize = SizeofResource(hInst, hResInfo);
hResData = LoadResource(hInst, hResInfo);
pRes = LockResource(hResData);
pResCopy = LocalAlloc(LMEM_FIXED, dwSize);
CopyMemory(pResCopy, pRes, dwSize);
FreeResource(hResData);

VerQueryValue(pResCopy, TEXT("\\"), (LPVOID*)&lpFfi, &uLen);

DWORD dwFileVersionMS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionMS;
DWORD dwFileVersionLS = lpFfi->dwFileVersionLS;

DWORD dwLeftMost     = HIWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
DWORD dwSecondLeft   = LOWORD(dwFileVersionMS);
DWORD dwSecondRight  = HIWORD(dwFileVersionLS);
DWORD dwRightMost    = LOWORD(dwFileVersionLS);

LocalFree(pResCopy);
```

**UPDATE:** this only works if you access the `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` struct only. If you need to access any other values, you must use `GetFileVersionInfo()`. Per Raymond Chen's blog:

[The first parameter to VerQueryValue really must be a buffer you obtained from GetFileVersionInfo](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061226-06/?p=28603)

> The documentation says that the first parameter to VerQueryValue must be a buffer returned by the GetFileVersionInfo function for a reason. **The buffer returned by GetFileVersionInfo is an opaque data block specifically formatted so that VerQueryValue will work**. You're not supposed to look inside that buffer, and you certainly can't try to "obtain the data some other way". Because **if you do, VerQueryValue will look for something in a buffer that is not formatted in the manner the function expects.**

Comment: +1 I just needed and used this. Thank you. One very minor comment: `FreeResource` call is not needed and returns `FALSE`, according to the docs.

Comment: Is there any official documentation of the fact that you have to take a copy of the block?

Comment: The documentation for [FreeResource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648044(v=vs.85).aspx) suggests that it should not be called

Comment: Version resources aren’t necessarily 100, can be any number. In the legacy project I’m working on it’s `MAKEINTRESOURCE( 1 )`

Comment: @Soonts true, but in the example given by the OP, it is 100.

Comment: @M.M [The first parameter to VerQueryValue really must be a buffer you obtained from GetFileVersionInfo](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20061226-06/?p=28603)

Comment: Do you really have to `LocalAlloc` the memory?  Could you use a `std::unique_ptr` instead ?

Comment: @Spencer It doesn't matter how the memory is allocated, as long as it is writable memory.

Comment: That should be part of the answer, then.  `LocalAlloc` has to be balanced with a call to `LocalFree` so maybe a `unique_ptr` is preferred here in C++.

Comment: @Spencer I already stated in my answer that the allocated memory has to be writable. Using `unique_ptr` is simply a matter of good memory management. Whether the memory is allocated with `LocalAlloc()`, `malloc()`,  `new[]`, etc has no bearing whatsoever on the behavior of `VerQueryValue()` itself, which is the root of the question.

Comment: Perhaps, but people will interpret your code to think you have to use `LocalAlloc`.

Comment: @Spencer anyone who makes that assumption clearly lacks adequate experience with the Win32 API and how it interacts with user-provided memory buffers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250274/discussion-between-spencer-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score -1):

The above would create a heap corruption error message in debug mode, such as "Free Heap block b753e70 modified at b753ed4 after it was freed". Someone has posted this problem many years ago at http://microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel.narkive.com/mqoHgVwM/verqueryvalue-bug. It is still hapenning today. One can make the message disappear by making dwSize sufficiently large, such as multiplying it by 4.