# Reading version from resource file dll project

Tags: java, c++, dll, resources

I have cpp window dll that has a resource file containing a version string.
I thought this version can be retrieved by the following logic:

```
    // Read version from resource file
    HMODULE hModule = GetModuleHandle(NULL);        

    HRSRC hVersion = FindResource(hModule, MAKEINTRESOURCE(VS_VERSION_INFO), RT_VERSION);

    // Convert version info to string
    if (hVersion) {
        HGLOBAL hGlobal = LoadResource(hModule, hVersion);
        if (hGlobal) {
            LPVOID lpVersion = LockResource(hGlobal);
            
            if (lpVersion) {
                VS_FIXEDFILEINFO* pFileInfo = nullptr;
                UINT dwLen = 0;
                if (VerQueryValue(lpVersion, L"\\", (LPVOID*)&pFileInfo, &dwLen) && pFileInfo) {
                    WORD major = HIWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS);
                    WORD minor = LOWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionMS);
                    WORD build = HIWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS);
                    WORD revision = LOWORD(pFileInfo->dwFileVersionLS);

                    string version = std::format("{}.{}.{}.{}", major, minor, build, revision);                     
                    logInfo(LOG_TITLE, std::format("Version: [{}]", version));

                    return version;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**NOW THE FUNNY PART**

I call the exported dll-methods from JAVA (via JNA) to query this version-string, so far so good:

**BUT** the version I get is the version from the Java-Runtime and NOT from the dll-resource file.

Does anybody has an idea how I can retrieve the version string from a resource file containing in the cpp-dll project, where this dll has exported methods to query exactly this version string. Thanx.

[image]

Comment: [`GetModuleHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandlew) - `lpModuleName` - _"...If this parameter is NULL, GetModuleHandle returns a handle to the file used to create the calling process (.exe file)...."_.  Fix: save the `hinstDLL` passed to [`DllMain`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/dlls/dllmain) in a global in the DLL as use that instead.

Comment: It is possible to read a `VS_FIXEDFILEINFO` from a `VS_VERSION_INFO` resource, HOWEVER there is an *undocumented* gotcha - `VerQueryValue()` *requires* the memory block to be writable, otherwise it will crash. So it can't directly use the pointer returned by `LockResource()` as resources are read-only. So, you have to make a copy of the resource data into a memory block that you allocate, and then you can pass that memory to `VerQueryValue()`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/13942403/65863

Comment: @Richard Critten Thank you that worked fine +1 :D